# Application startup error while deploying java spring-boot app to GCP app engine

Tags: java, rest, maven, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform

While deploying to GCP my build is successful but I am facing Application Startup Error. The app is running fine at localhost.

The error says: **Application startup error.**

My pom.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>catapi</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>catapi</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>42.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                    <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My application.properties is:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql=true

spring.cloud.gcp.projectId=swathitest1
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instanceName=swathi-db
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.databaseName=test
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.userName=postgres
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.password=Welcome1!

spring.cloud.gcp.sql.jdbcDriver=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.jdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql://google/test?socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory&socketFactoryArg=swathitest1:asia-south1:swathi-db


spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://35.200.222.222:5432/test
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=Welcome1!

spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.initialize=true
spring.datasource.schema=classpath:/schema.sql
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true
```

Do I need to add any other dependencies to pom.xml? or any changes required in my application.properties? Please guide me.

The full error stack trace is:
[error_log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUytX.png)

Comment: Can you please provide the detailed stack trace for this ?

Comment: "version": "0.0.1", "verbosity": "ERROR", "timestamp": "2019-06-04T09:44:18.664Z", "message": "(gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] \nApplication startup error:\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) [spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.3.RELEASE]\n\tat

Comment: @Ananthapadmanabhan Please have a look.

Comment: Is this the entire log available ? If possible can you please add extended log to the question itself by editing.Stack traces provide an idea about what went wrong and where. Also which gcp service are you using ? Compute Engine ?

Comment: @Ananthapadmanabhan I have edited the question. Please have a look.

Comment: I am using Google App Engine.